# Twitter npm package - how to apply multiple query parameters

Tags: node.js, twitter, npm

As I found out in this post ([link](http://thesocialchic.com/2013/04/26/how-to-master-twitter-search/)) Twitter Search API allows to exclude certain types of tweets like retweets or tweets that contain links in them.

How could this be applied to the Twitter npm package ([link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/twitter))?

For example:

```
client.get('search/tweets', {
  q: 'some query',
  exclude: 'retweets',
  exclude: 'links'
}, function(error, tweets, response) {
  console.log(tweets);
});
```

This request would only consider the last parameter - `exclude: 'links'`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
q: 'some query -filter:links -filter:retweets',
```

but I see, that according official docs you couldn't filter by retweets - https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/search

Ensure all parameters are properly URL encoded.